# Problem with correctly placing results in specific list in python

Tags: python, ellipse, astropy

I am currently trying to run a set of images (masked arrays / masked 'fits' files) of m87 through an isophote fitting function. Hereby one reference fit has been performed earlier in the script, which provides the function with the isophotes geometry, that are then used to sample the remaining images of the galaxy. The function looks as follows:

```
from photutils.isophote import EllipseSample, Isophote, IsophoteList
from photutils.isophote.isophote import Isophote, IsophoteList

test_set = [images_masked[0], images_masked[1]]
isolist_temp = []

def isophote_sampling(data_set):
    for iso in uvw2_isolist_nclp3[1:]:
        for data in test_set:
            g = iso.sample.geometry
            sample = EllipseSample(data, g.sma, geometry=g, sclip=3.0, nclip=3)
            sample.update()
            iso_ = Isophote(sample, 0, True, 0)
        isolist_temp.append(iso_)
        isolist_fin = IsophoteList(isolist_temp)
    return isolist_fin

isolist_sampled = list(map(isophote_sampling,test_set))
```

To access the results in detail one must convert to an indexable table:

```
isolist_results =[]
for isolist in isolist_sampled:
    isolist_tab = isolist.to_table()
    isolist_results.append(isolist_tab)
```

The idea is that the final product of this piece of code, is a list containing lists which are the results of the respective image, which the fit is being performed on. So basically something like this:

```
isolist_results = [[results from image0], [results from image1], ...]
```

I want to be able to access the isolist_results, be able to select a certain result and within it, the first three columns (which correspond to 'sma'-semi-major-axis, 'intens'-isophote intensity, 'intens_err'-corresponding error). This will allow me to simply give the function my full set of images and after the fit access, plot and compute different comparisons between them.
The current result looks as follows:

```
[<QTable length=138>
       sma                 intens         ... niter stop_code
                                          ...                
     float64              float64         ... int64   int64  
------------------ ---------------------- ... ----- ---------
0.5478081360044621    0.13135528023713275 ...     0         0
0.6025889496049083     0.1299246647753987 ...     0         0
0.6628478445653991    0.12836718613254233 ...     0         0
0.7291326290219391    0.12667273127860207 ...     0         0
 0.802045891924133    0.12483448451703007 ...     0         0
0.8822504811165464    0.12284968122832181 ...     0         0
 0.970475529228201    0.12069334888176463 ...     0         0
 1.067523082151021    0.11792209677230417 ...     0         0
1.1742753903661232    0.11416709361894391 ...     0         0
               ...                    ... ...   ...       ...
       sma                 intens         ... niter stop_code
                                          ...                
     float64              float64         ... int64   int64  
------------------ ---------------------- ... ----- ---------
0.5478081360044621    0.13135528023713275 ...     0         0
0.6025889496049083     0.1299246647753987 ...     0         0
0.6628478445653991    0.12836718613254233 ...     0         0
0.7291326290219391    0.12667273127860207 ...     0         0
 0.802045891924133    0.12483448451703007 ...     0         0
0.8822504811165464    0.12284968122832181 ...     0         0
 0.970475529228201    0.12069334888176463 ...     0         0
 1.067523082151021    0.11792209677230417 ...     0         0
1.1742753903661232    0.11416709361894391 ...     0         0
               ...                    ... ...   ...       ...
```

As you can see, the problem is the function only putting in one of the results for all iterations through the input. Moving the 'isolist_temp.append(iso_)' command one indent to the right, leads to:

```
[<QTable length=276>
       sma                 intens         ... niter stop_code
                                          ...                
     float64              float64         ... int64   int64  
------------------ ---------------------- ... ----- ---------
0.5478081360044621    0.21974529309537935 ...     0         0
0.5478081360044621    0.13135528023713275 ...     0         0
0.6025889496049083    0.21833267680395468 ...     0         0
0.6025889496049083     0.1299246647753987 ...     0         0
0.6628478445653991    0.21679269241579674 ...     0         0
0.6628478445653991    0.12836718613254233 ...     0         0
0.7291326290219391    0.21511467290298006 ...     0         0
0.7291326290219391    0.12667273127860207 ...     0         0
 0.802045891924133    0.21329102749191028 ...     0         0
               ...                    ... ...   ...       ...
       sma                 intens         ... niter stop_code
                                          ...                
     float64              float64         ... int64   int64  
------------------ ---------------------- ... ----- ---------
0.5478081360044621    0.21974529309537935 ...     0         0
0.5478081360044621    0.13135528023713275 ...     0         0
0.6025889496049083    0.21833267680395468 ...     0         0
0.6025889496049083     0.1299246647753987 ...     0         0
0.6628478445653991    0.21679269241579674 ...     0         0
0.6628478445653991    0.12836718613254233 ...     0         0
0.7291326290219391    0.21511467290298006 ...     0         0
0.7291326290219391    0.12667273127860207 ...     0         0
 0.802045891924133    0.21329102749191028 ...     0         0
               ...                    ... ...   ...       ...
```

As you can see, now both results are being put into the final list, but for each sma value we now have both fit results within the same entry in the final list, repeating itself for all items in the final list.

Note:

- The map() command is used to take care of the sorting of the results into the final list 'isolist_sampled', which then in the next loop gets converted into accessible tables.
- This is just a small excerpt of the full notebook. So yes, I loaded all packages needed for this to work out.
- I am by no means a python expert, so please be gentle ;)

**Question:**
What do I need to change in the function or after, in order to achieve the final list as described above (each entry corresponding to the full array/list of results of the respective input image)?
I am assuming it's a trivial correction, but I just can't seem to find it. Thanks for any help you can give me on this.

**Edit:**
Plotting the latter 'isolist_results' looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nyhy.png).
So in other words, right now both entries in 'isolist_results' contain both results, but I want entry 1 to contain the result of image 1 and entry 2 contain the other. I hope this clears up my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below looks wrong to me - should you not be appending "iso_" to isolist_temp within the for loop?

```
for data in test_set:
    g = iso.sample.geometry
    sample = EllipseSample(data, g.sma, geometry=g, sclip=3.0, nclip=3)
    sample.update()
    iso_ = Isophote(sample, 0, True, 0)
isolist_temp.append(iso_)
isolist_fin = IsophoteList(isolist_temp)
```

I'd also be concerned that you aren't resetting isolist_temp before entering the for data loop - without knowing exactly what you are doing it smells wrong.

Below is more toward the shape of solution that usually makes more sense for the loop.

```
for iso in uvw2_isolist_nclp3[1:]:
    isolist_temp = []
    for data in test_set:
        g = iso.sample.geometry
        sample = EllipseSample(data, g.sma, geometry=g, sclip=3.0, nclip=3)
        sample.update()
        iso_ = Isophote(sample, 0, True, 0)
        isolist_temp.append(iso_)
    isolist_fin = IsophoteList(isolist_temp)
return isolist_fin
```

Comment: That's what I meant by moving the 'isolist_temp.append(iso_)' command one indent to the right. It works, but now both results are within each entry of the isolist_results list. I want one results-list for each entry within the isolist_results. Resetting the isolist_temp sounds like a good idea. Let me try that.

Comment: Resetting the list worked perfectly! I also split the function into the analysis and after it I implemented the loop for sorting into the correct list and column.